# Django duplicate column name: Username

Tags: django, django-models

I'm getting the following error when I try to migrate:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: duplicate column name: Username
```

howerever I don't even have a username field. I'm attaching botht the model and the 0001_initial.py file in the migrations folder for this app as instructed in the comments.

The model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser



class User(AbstractUser):
FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
LastName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
#profile_pic = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='profile_pics')
username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True,
validators=[RegexValidator(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters, underscores, and periods are allowed in your username.')])
Email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
RoleChoices = [('A','Admin'),('D','Developer'),('O','Observer')]
Role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=RoleChoices)
```

And the following is the 0001_initial.py file

```
 import django.contrib.auth.models
 import django.contrib.auth.validators
 import django.core.validators
 from django.db import migrations, models
 import django.utils.timezone


 class Migration(migrations.Migration):



initial = True

dependencies = [
    ('auth', '0011_update_proxy_permissions'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='User',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
            ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
            ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
            ('username', models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=150, unique=True, validators=[django.contrib.auth.validators.UnicodeUsernameValidator()], verbose_name='username')),
            ('first_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, verbose_name='first name')),
            ('last_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150, verbose_name='last name')),
            ('email', models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=254, verbose_name='email address')),
            ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.', verbose_name='staff status')),
            ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.', verbose_name='active')),
            ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='date joined')),
            ('FirstName', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
            ('LastName', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
            ('Username', models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, validators=[django.core.validators.RegexValidator('^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters, underscores, and periods are allowed in your username.')])),
            ('Email', models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)),
            ('IsBoardAdmin', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
            ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
            ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
        ],
        options={
            'verbose_name': 'user',
            'verbose_name_plural': 'users',
            'abstract': False,
        },
        managers=[
            ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
        ],
    ),
]
```

Comment: Share the model you are migrating together with the migration file. Note that if you *inherit* models, you inherit the corresponding fields.

Comment: Furthermore based on the error, you perhaps made manual migrations: so altering the table *without* a migration file.